# Discrete Mathematics - Defining Infinite using First Order Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, first-order-logic

I am having difficulty understanding first order logic for advanced problems. Is there a good resource to learn more, or does it just take practice? This is the problem I don't know how to do.

Define Inf(S) in first order logic over the universe Natural Numbers.

Any ideas where to start, or the steps to do this?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: A subset $S$ of the natural numbers is infinite if and only it has no largest member. (I’m assuming that your formal language includes either $<$ or $\le$.)

Comment: So it would be something along the lines of this?

∃S ⊆ Nat: (∀y ∈ S: (∀x ∈ S: x > y))

Comment: @ztoolson: You don’t want that $\exists S$ at all: you’re trying to write a formula $mbox{Inf}(S)$, where $S$ is a variable, that says that $S$ is infinite. For example a formula $E(n)$ that says that the natural number $n$ is even is $\exists k\in\Bbb N(n=2k)$; $n$ is a free variable, not one that’s bound by a quantifier. Now take a look at the rest of what you wrote: $\forall y\in S\forall x\in S(x>y)$. That says that every member of $S$ is greater than every member of $S$ **including itself**, which clearly can’t be right. You want to say that **for each** member of $S$ there is ...?

Comment: Would this be right then?
∃x,y ∈ N(x>y);
How would I specify for each member of S?

Comment: @ztoolson: That merely says that $\Bbb N$ has at least two elements. Follow the English: **for each** $n\in\Bbb N$ **there is an** $m\in\Bbb N$ **such that** $m>n$. What’s the symbolic equivalent?

Comment: @Brain That makes a lot more sense than what I was doing. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @ztoolson: You’re welcome!